# Jslider values Min/Max

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jslider (minprice, maxprice), like in this exemple:
http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/
How to get min and max values? h return me only the current value :/

```
  jQuery("#Slider5").slider({ from: 0, to: 3000, step: 10, dimension: '', scale: ['0', '1000', '2000', '3000'], limits: false, calculate: function( value ){
                            var h = value;
                            return (h+" $");
                          }})
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and it worked exactly as **pauljz** and **jacktheripper** describe.

Here is my code for using the 'value' parameter:

```
callback: function( value ){
alert("values: " + value.toString());
}
```

displays, for example: "values: 1;12"

Here is my code using the slider() method:

```
callback: function( not_used ){
var values = $("#Slider5").slider("value");
alert("values using .slider() method: " + values.toString());
}
```

displays, for example: "values using .slider() method: 1;12"

I also separated the values like this:

```
callback: function( values ){
var splitVals = values.split(';');
alert("separate values: " + splitVals[0] + ", " + splitVals[1]);
}
```

I'm using jSlider from Egor Khmelev:  http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#Slider5').slider("value");`.  It'll return something like `"600;720"` which you can split to get the min/max.

Comment: Thanks a lot,i've tried to add alert($('#Slider5').slider("value")) before the return, it duplicate to me the slider and didn't return to me the current values

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = $("#Slider5").slider("value")
```

Will return an array of values. The min value will be `values[0]` and the max value `values[1]`.

Comment: Thansk a lot, i've tried to catch the value in the hidden like this:
var values = $('#Slider5').slider("value");
$('input[name=val]').val(values);
</script>
<input type="text" id="val" name="val" value="0">
didn't work :/

Comment: See if `$('input[name=val]').val(values[0] + '' + values[1]);` works

Comment: not really, the value of the hidden didn't change, i think that i should add a function that change on live the value of the hidden,  isn't possible to make this in my function jQuery("#Slider5").slider(...) ?

Comment: i've checked my $_POST it seems to be set in a var named AREA :) that's great!
Thanks again